# Use pybind11 with venv

Tags: python, c++, python-venv, pybind11

I have a virtual environment defined using `venv` and I am trying to build a python module using c++ code and the `pybind11` library. The problem is that, when using the virtual environment, python does not see the new module.

This is the code in file `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int myadd(int a, int b) {
      return a + b;
}

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
   m.def("myadd", &myadd);
}
```

This is the command I use to build the Python module `example` (virtual environment activated)

```bash
c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC $(python -m pybind11 --includes) main.cpp -o example.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

When trying to import the module `example`, Python throws the following error:

```py
>>> import example                                                                         
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                         
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                      
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'example'
```

On the other hand, without using the virtual environment it all works.

What is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you *put* the compiled module? And where are you running Python from? If you don't run Python with the same working directory that contains the module, and the module isn't installed into the venv, Python won't find it. In general, it's better to build `pybind11` extensions using a `setup.py` file (which will make it trivial to build a package and install it into the venv) rather than manually running the compile commands (where it's *very* easy to get something slightly wrong, e.g. wrong naming conventions, wrong install location, mismatched compiler from Python's, etc.

Comment: The file ```main.cpp``` and the compiled module are in the same folder ```myproject```. I am also running python from the same folder. I know that it's easier to use the ```setup.py``` file to install the module but I have to work on the code developed by others and they are not using it. What I don't understand is that without using the virtual environment everything works. So maybe I have to change something on the compile command but I do not know what to change

Comment: Whay python version are you running in your venv?

Comment: The python version is 3.9.14

Comment: Your output extension module is tagged for python 3.10. Try `-o example.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`